# Could not convert 'notes' from 'std::array<double, 6u>' to 'std::array<double, 7u>

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that is the same as `push_back()` but it doesn't work.

How I can resolve this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double add(array<double, 6> const& tab);
void add_push_back(array<double, 6+1> tab);

int main()
{
    const int tailleTab{6};
    array<double, tailleTab> notes = { 11.0, 9.5, 8.4, 12.0, 14.01, 12.03 };
    double myMoyenne{};
    myMoyenne = add(notes);
    cout << myMoyenne;

    add_push_back(notes);

    for (auto note: notes){
        cout << note << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

double add(array<double, 6> const& tab){
    double result{};
    for (double note: tab){
        result += note;
    }
    result /= tab.size();
    return result;
}

void add_push_back(array<double, 6+1> tab){
    array<double, 6+1> push;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tab.size(); ++i){
        push.at(i) += tab.at(i);
    }
    push.at(7) = {7};
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < push.size(); ++i){
        tab.at(i) += push.at(i);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: could not convert 'notes' from 'std::array<double, 6u>' to 'std::array<double, 7u>'|
```

Comment: Aside from the answer by @mockinterface, if `push` has size 7, it is not allowed to assign to `push.at(7)`. Valid indices are numbered 0 through 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass an `std::array` containing 6 elements into a function expecting an `std::array` with 7 elements because `std::array<type, 6>` is a *different type* from an `std::array<type, 7>`. Template classes with different template parameters are considered by the compiler to be different types.

To solve your immediate problem, you need to change the `tab` parameter for `add_push_back` from an `array<double, 6+1>` to an `array<double, 6>`.

**However**, I'd suggest that you use an `std::vector` or `std::deque` which are much more suited to resizing. A quick look at your code suggests that you can't even do what you're trying to do with an array. You can't dynamically resize an `std::array` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array size mismatch. The `notes` array has 6 elements, while 7 are expected. See `add_push_back`'s signature, the argument is `array<double, 6+1>`.